# "UserId, Password or Account is invalid" for sqlalchemy Teradata

Tags: sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy, anaconda, teradata

I am trying to connect to Teradata with sqlalchemy in Python (Anaconda) like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

conn_string = 'teradata://' + user + ':' + passw + '@' + host + '/?logmech=LDAP'

eng = create_engine(conn_string)
# execute sql
sql = 'select top 10 * from some_table'
result = eng.execute(sql)
```

I am getting this error, even though I have checked many times to confirm they are correct:

```
DatabaseError: (teradata.api.DatabaseError) (210, '[28000] [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]
[Teradata Database] (210) The UserId, Password or Account is invalid. FailCode = -8017')
```

I can confirm that other Python scripts connect to the same DB using pyodbc and also when I connect using DBeaver. So the user/password are good. I am using sqlalchemy because I want to insert a dataframe into a table using df.to_sql, which seems not available if I use the pyodbc connector.

Is it possible this error means something other than what it says? Maybe I need some other connection parameter?

Comment: *The UserId, Password or Account is invalid* is a generic error and might include other causes, see https://docs.teradata.com/reader/Wx6YYmyFQHvyRRCOvS9hVQ/CHgDBHrfuuv~cCmsePy1DQ Check `dbc.LogonOffV` to see a bit more detail in the `Event` column

Comment: Note that _teradatasql_  (_teradatasqlalchemy_ module) is now the preferred / supported dialect over _teradata_ (_sqlalchemy-teradata_). For the older driver that relies on ODBC, the URL keyword should be `Authentication` or `MechanismName` (though `logmech` would be correct for the new driver).. And of course if the password or username contain special characters, you need to "urlquote" them.